# iOS // Resizing a UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, resize

It seems to be a very common question, but yet I haven't found any solution.

I'm trying to resize a `UIWebView` containing a playing HTML5 video in a `<video>` tag.

```
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
        self.webView.frame = newFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        DDLogInfo(@"Enter fullscreen anim completed");
    }];
```

When I run this code, the height goes to 768 instantly, while x y and width animate properly.
I have also tried to animate the bounds instead, same result, and the superview, same result.

I just cannot get to animate this small web view to a fullscreen size properly.

Has anyone found a solution for that? I would love to hear it!

Thanks :)

Comment: Is your project using auto layout?

Comment: It's not, I also tried with autolayout and it didn't work